# Mirror bar plot with plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I want to know how to mirror 2 kinds of bars(positive number and negative number) in vertical like the picture below:

[image]

So far I can only make them mirror but standing side by side like:

[image]

Data:

```
library(plotly)
time <- c("2018-10","2018-11","2018-12")
add <- c(20,15,20)
delete <- c(-5,-10,-2)
total <- c(60,65,83)
df <- data.frame(time,add,delete,total)

plot_ly(df) %>%
    add_trace(x = ~time, y = ~add, type = 'bar', name = 'add',
              marker = list(color = '#33adff'),
              hovertemplate = paste('add: %{y}',
                                    '<br>time: %{x}<br>')) %>%
    add_trace(x = ~time, y = ~delete, type = 'bar', name = 'delete',
              marker = list(color = '#ff6666'),
              hovertemplate = paste('delete: %{y}',
                                    '<br>time: %{x}<br>'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved using `barmode="overlay"`.
 
You need to set the `df` dataset in long data format.

```
library(plotly)
time <- c("2018-10","2018-11","2018-12")
add <- c(20,15,20)
delete <- c(-5,-10,-2)
total <- c(60,65,83)
n <- length(time)
df <- data.frame(time=rep(time,2), y=c(add, delete), grp=rep(c("Add","Delete"),each=n))

plot_ly(df) %>%
    add_trace(x = ~time, y = ~y, color=~grp, text=~grp, type = 'bar', 
              marker = list(color = c(rep('#33adff',n), rep('#ff6666',n))),
              hovertemplate = paste('%{text}: %{y}', '<br>time: %{x}<br>')) %>%
    layout(barmode="overlay")
```

[image]